# Reset Password with Custom Policies in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

How do I reset a user's password when using [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom)?  Based upon this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375169/azure-ad-b2c-with-custom-policies-unable-to-authenticate-user-with-temporary-pa), I can't use [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com) as it assigns a temporary password that must be changed on next sign-in.

Am I forced to use the [graph api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)?  Any other options?

Comment: Did you try using password reset policy (custom policy)? You seeing any issues using that too?

Comment: duh!  no, I didn't.  I used the portal's password reset feature.

I just tried the reset policy and that worked!  thanks!

Question still remains though, for admins, how do they reset passwords on behalf of the user?

Comment: For admins it is pretty straight to reset password of other users from Users and Groups blade. You see any issues from using that?

Comment: yes, it forces a password change on next login which is not support w/ custom policies

Comment: True it doesn't support  from custom policy . But it support from Sign-in (Basic not custom) policy.

Comment: As of now (till B2C support change temporary password up on first login from custom policy)It is good idea to inform users to reset the password once you create users from portal. New users always start their journey from reset password.

Answer (score 1):

Copying the answer from the stack overflow post that you linked,

Both a "sign-up or sign-in policy" or "custom policy" do not support the Azure Active Directory forceChangePasswordNextLogin flag. (forceChangePasswordNextLogin will only work with a "sign-up policy") There is a feature request tracking this here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16861051-aadb2c-force-password-reset

Comment: there has to be a way to reset the password if I'm using custom policies