# Azure AD B2C: custom policy local account signin/signup fails

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I try to build an invitation flow using custom policies.

My approach was to combine the invitation part of the [WingTipGamesB2C policies](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Policies) with the [custom policy starter pack](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/tree/master/SocialAndLocalAccounts).

The invitation seems to work fine; when using the invitation link and providing the user data (display name, password), the user is created in the Azure AD.

But I am not able to login with this user; the sign in dialog shows "Invalid username or password." (while with a wrong password "Your password is incorrect" is shown).

Using the builtin signin policy, the login works as expected.

b2crecorder shows the following log:

```
SelfAssertedMessageValidationHandler
The message was received from null
Validation via SelfAssertedAttributeProvider
Additional validation is required...
OperativeTechnicalProfile is login-NonInteractive
Mapping default value 'undefined' to policy 'client_id'
Mapping default value 'undefined' to policy 'resource_id'
Mapping 'username' partner claim type to 'signInName' policy claim type
Mapping default value 'undefined' to policy 'grant_type'
Mapping default value 'undefined' to policy 'scope'
Mapping default value 'undefined' to policy 'nca'
Using validation endpoint at: https://login.microsoftonline.com/foo.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
Orchestration Step: 1
RA: 0
Protocol selected by the caller: OAUTH2
Communications with the caller handled by: OAuth2ProtocolProvider
IC: True
OAuth2 Message: MSG(c693a69c-4a15-4ef5-b85d-a9a6a3f3298f) Message Detail
ValidationRequest:
ValidationResponse:
Exception:
Exception of type 'Web.TPEngine.Providers.BadArgumentRetryNeededException' was thrown.
```

This looks like the same error as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45375169/azure-ad-b2c-with-custom-policies-unable-to-authenticate-user-with-temporary-pa), but should be a different problem, as the problem was the "forceChangePasswordNextLogin" flag in there, while the users that are created by the invitation should not have this flag.

I checked that the `IdentityExperienceFramework` and `ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework` apps are correctly created and permissions are granted. They are also referenced as documented in the `TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml`.

How can I fix this? What can I do to further debug this problem? I used both Application Insights and the b2crecorder without getting enough information about the failure.

Additional information:
* The custom signup does also not work
* Signing up/in via 3rd party IDP (Google) works

Comment: What type of local accounts?  email or username?

Comment: @spottedmahn I never thought about the type of local accounts; the invitation/signup dialog as well as the signin dialog expect an email address for signing up/in, no username

Comment: Have you tried to sign-in with a built-in sign-in or sign-in/up policy?  Will help fork the issue: 1) custom issue or 2) user creation issue

Comment: @spottedmahn yes, sign-in for users that were created by the invitation flow works with a builtin sign-in policy, as described. so I guess it is the first option?

Comment: Agreed.  I would try to remove the invitation part of the equation for now. Maybe the problem is the custom policy for sign-in.  Create a user w/ a built-in sign-up policy.  Try to sign-in using ur custom policy for that user.

Comment: Yes, it is the sign-in policy; I tried that now and, as expected, couldn't login using the custom policy with the user that I created using the builtin policy, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out what my problem was; In the `login-NonInteractive` technical profile, I replaced the strange looking `<Item Key="ProviderName">https://sts.windows.net/</Item>` by some nice looking name, assuming that it was just some irrelevant string (e.g for the google IdP, I could use `<Item Key="ProviderName">Google</Item>` ...)

Well, it seems to be important. When restoring the original providername, signin works perfectly.

Just answering my own question here, as I hope this will save somebody else's time.